# Problem deploying an Azure Function to a Function App

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have been trying to deploy an Azure function from Visual Studio Code to a function app on Azure. I am getting a message that the deployment was successful, but the Azure function does not appear in the function app on Azure. Here is the image of my file structure on VS Code. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: file structure]

I tried to change the configuration of the host.json file, but the same problem keeps happening.

[image: code capture]

Comment: Please share your full function code?

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when Function Syntax is incorrect, Code is incorrect, Deployed files are not properly getting deployed in correct folder structure.  which prevents Azure function to recognize code as function.

- Make sure proper Azure Function syntax is being used.
- Make sure code is running Locally fine by running locally  in vs code.

I deployed HTTP trigger function, it worked perfectly fine.

#### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 on the recommendation to check that the code is running locally before deploying to Azure Functions if you are seeing this kind of behavior. I have seen this several times with Python code and it was always my code, never the Azure Functions service, that was at fault.